# Select and Drag a rectangle using mouse javascript

Tags: javascript, css

I have a rectangle I would like to select it by using mouse and drag it all the sides using mouse. Can some please suggest me how to achieve this?

[image: I would like to do the same way as in an image]

Comment: Do you mean dragging the rectangle's sides and corners to change its size?

Comment: yes I want to change the size by dragging the rectangle sides using java script OR CSS..

Comment: A simple idea is to use divs to simulate sides and corners, change cursors of them, bind `mousedown` and `mousemove` events to them. An example is [Jcrop](http://deepliquid.com/projects/Jcrop/demos.php)

Answer (score 0):

jQuery UI is what you need.

Draggable: http://jqueryui.com/draggable/

Droppable: http://jqueryui.com/droppable/

Selectable: http://jqueryui.com/selectable/

Answer (score 0):

http://fabricjs.com/controls/

This is exactly what you are looking for,i have personally used this fabricjs and its really good.

You can see the code required on the right side in that link.

Comment: Nevin, Yes exactly i need in the same way..Can't we achieve it using regular Java script?

Comment: Yes you can,you have to code it.
I just suggested a simpler way by using fabric.
and so did cyadvert.
We both provided a simpler way of doing it.